# Creating a new array type compatible with `godot::Variant`?

Tags: c++, vector, godot

Writing an add-on with GDExtension, I'm looking to return an array of custom types on Godot 4. My first thought was writing a type like `godot::Vector<godot::Ref<MyStruct>>`, but I discovered that the compiler complains, as this new type is incompatible with `godot::Variant`.

So, I would like to know how I'm supposed to fulfil the requirements imposed by `godot-cpp`. Here the compiler error:

```
➜  scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Auto-detected 12 CPU cores available for build parallelism. Using 11 cores by default. You can override it with the -j argument.
Building for architecture x86_64 on platform linux
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `godot-cpp/bin/libgodot-cpp.linux.template_debug.x86_64.a' is up to date.
g++ -o godot/hand_ranking_evaluation.os -c -std=c++17 -fPIC -Wwrite-strings -m64 -march=x86-64 -O2 -fPIC -DLINUX_ENABLED -DUNIX_ENABLED -DDEBUG_ENABLED -DDEBUG_METHODS_ENABLED -DNDEBUG -Igodot-cpp/gdextension -Igodot-cpp/include -Igodot-cpp/gen/include -I/nix/store/5hch4vqzwan8ksab4pfpyrbb7wvvv3ad-cxxtest-4.4/include -I/nix/store/7nbh3b6hhjqjs3nfy529g38l85iv46i9-openssl-3.0.11-dev/include -Isrc -Iompeval/omp -Igodot godot/hand_ranking_evaluation.cpp
g++ -o godot/register_types.os -c -std=c++17 -fPIC -Wwrite-strings -m64 -march=x86-64 -O2 -fPIC -DLINUX_ENABLED -DUNIX_ENABLED -DDEBUG_ENABLED -DDEBUG_METHODS_ENABLED -DNDEBUG -Igodot-cpp/gdextension -Igodot-cpp/include -Igodot-cpp/gen/include -I/nix/store/5hch4vqzwan8ksab4pfpyrbb7wvvv3ad-cxxtest-4.4/include -I/nix/store/7nbh3b6hhjqjs3nfy529g38l85iv46i9-openssl-3.0.11-dev/include -Isrc -Iompeval/omp -Igodot godot/register_types.cpp
In file included from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp:38,
                 from godot-cpp/gen/include/godot_cpp/classes/ref_counted.hpp:39,
                 from godot/../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/classes/ref.hpp:37,
                 from godot/poker.hpp:5,
                 from godot/hand_ranking_evaluation.cpp:1:
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'GDExtensionVariantType godot::MethodBindTR<R, P>::gen_argument_type(int) const [with R = godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:446:33:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:450:71: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  450 |                         return GDExtensionVariantType(GetTypeInfo<R>::VARIANT_TYPE);
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'godot::PropertyInfo godot::MethodBindTR<R, P>::gen_argument_type_info(int) const [with R = godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:454:23:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:460:62: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  460 |                         return GetTypeInfo<R>::get_class_info();
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'GDExtensionClassMethodArgumentMetadata godot::MethodBindTR<R, P>::get_argument_metadata(int) const [with R = godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:468:49:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:472:48: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  472 |                         return GetTypeInfo<R>::METADATA;
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:34:
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_with_variant_args_ret_helper(T*, R (T::*)(P ...), const Variant**, Variant&, GDExtensionCallError&, IndexSequence<Is ...>) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; R = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}; long unsigned int ...Is = {}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:381:35:   required from 'void godot::call_with_variant_args_ret_dv(T*, R (T::*)(P ...), const void* const*, int, Variant&, GDExtensionCallError&, const std::vector<Variant>&) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; R = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}; GDExtensionConstVariantPtr = const void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:481:32:   required from 'godot::Variant godot::MethodBindTR<R, P>::call(GDExtensionClassInstancePtr, const void* const*, GDExtensionInt, GDExtensionCallError&) const [with R = godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}; GDExtensionClassInstancePtr = void*; GDExtensionConstVariantPtr = const void*; GDExtensionInt = long int]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:476:18:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:261:15: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'godot::Variant' and 'godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >')
  261 |         r_ret = (p_instance->*p_method)(VariantCasterAndValidate<P>::cast(p_args, Is, r_error)...);
      |         ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/typed_array.hpp:35,
                 from godot-cpp/gen/include/godot_cpp/classes/object.hpp:41,
                 from godot/../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/classes/ref.hpp:36:
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:252:18: note: candidate: 'godot::Variant& godot::Variant::operator=(const godot::Variant&)'
  252 |         Variant &operator=(const Variant &other);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:252:43: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >' to 'const godot::Variant&'
  252 |         Variant &operator=(const Variant &other);
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:253:18: note: candidate: 'godot::Variant& godot::Variant::operator=(godot::Variant&&)'
  253 |         Variant &operator=(Variant &&other);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:253:38: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >' to 'godot::Variant&&'
  253 |         Variant &operator=(Variant &&other);
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_with_ptr_args_ret_helper(T*, R (T::*)(P ...), const void* const*, void*, IndexSequence<Is ...>) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; R = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}; long unsigned int ...Is = {}; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:224:43:   required from 'void godot::call_with_ptr_args(T*, R (T::*)(P ...), const void* const*, void*) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; R = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:489:36:   required from 'void godot::MethodBindTR<R, P>::ptrcall(GDExtensionClassInstancePtr, const void* const*, GDExtensionTypePtr) const [with R = godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; P = {}; GDExtensionClassInstancePtr = void*; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*; GDExtensionTypePtr = void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:485:15:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:204:28: error: 'encode' is not a member of 'godot::PtrToArg<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> > >'
  204 |         PtrToArg<R>::encode((p_instance->*p_method)(PtrToArg<P>::convert(p_args[Is])...), r_ret);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_get_argument_type_helper(int, int&, GDExtensionVariantType&) [with Q = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:440:53:   required from 'GDExtensionVariantType godot::call_get_argument_type(int) [with P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:295:39:   required from 'GDExtensionVariantType godot::MethodBindT<P>::gen_argument_type(int) const [with P = {godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:293:33:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:429:63: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  429 |                 type = GDExtensionVariantType(GetTypeInfo<Q>::VARIANT_TYPE);
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_get_argument_type_info_helper(int, int&, PropertyInfo&) [with Q = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:459:58:   required from 'void godot::call_get_argument_type_info(int, PropertyInfo&) [with P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:304:37:   required from 'godot::PropertyInfo godot::MethodBindT<P>::gen_argument_type_info(int) const [with P = {godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:301:23:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:449:54: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  449 |                 info = GetTypeInfo<Q>::get_class_info();
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_get_argument_metadata_helper(int, int&, GDExtensionClassMethodArgumentMetadata&) [with Q = Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:479:57:   required from 'GDExtensionClassMethodArgumentMetadata godot::call_get_argument_metadata(int) [with P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:316:42:   required from 'GDExtensionClassMethodArgumentMetadata godot::MethodBindT<P>::get_argument_metadata(int) const [with P = {godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:315:49:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:467:38: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  467 |                 md = GetTypeInfo<Q>::METADATA;
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_with_ptr_args_helper(T*, void (T::*)(P ...), const void* const*, IndexSequence<Is ...>) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}; long unsigned int ...Is = {0}; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:214:36:   required from 'void godot::call_with_ptr_args(T*, void (T::*)(P ...), const void* const*, void*) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:331:33:   required from 'void godot::MethodBindT<P>::ptrcall(GDExtensionClassInstancePtr, const void* const*, GDExtensionTypePtr) const [with P = {godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}; GDExtensionClassInstancePtr = void*; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*; GDExtensionTypePtr = void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:327:15:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:194:53: error: 'convert' is not a member of 'godot::PtrToArg<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> > >'
  194 |         (p_instance->*p_method)(PtrToArg<P>::convert(p_args[Is])...);
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'static T godot::VariantCasterAndValidate<T>::cast(const godot::Variant**, uint32_t, GDExtensionCallError&) [with T = godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >; uint32_t = unsigned int]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:237:59:   required from 'void godot::call_with_variant_args_helper(T*, void (T::*)(P ...), const Variant**, GDExtensionCallError&, IndexSequence<Is ...>) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}; long unsigned int ...Is = {0}]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:311:31:   required from 'void godot::call_with_variant_args_dv(T*, void (T::*)(P ...), const void* const*, int, GDExtensionCallError&, const std::vector<Variant>&) [with T = _gde_UnexistingClass; P = {Vector<Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}; GDExtensionConstVariantPtr = const void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:323:28:   required from 'godot::Variant godot::MethodBindT<P>::call(GDExtensionClassInstancePtr, const void* const*, GDExtensionInt, GDExtensionCallError&) const [with P = {godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >}; GDExtensionClassInstancePtr = void*; GDExtensionConstVariantPtr = const void*; GDExtensionInt = long int]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:319:18:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:150:89: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<godot::Vector<godot::Ref<HandRankEvaluation> >, void>' used in nested name specifier
  150 |                 GDExtensionVariantType argtype = GDExtensionVariantType(GetTypeInfo<T>::VARIANT_TYPE);
      |                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
scons: *** [godot/hand_ranking_evaluation.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: `godot::Vector<godot::Ref<MyStruct>>` is not a supported type in the GDExtension API. This is because `Ref<MyStruct>` is a custom type and the GDExtension API doesn't know how to handle a vector of these.

Comment: @Kozydot not exactly true. The GDExtension API doesn't handle `godot::Vector`s of any type and `godot::Ref<T>` is just a smart pointer for `godot::RefCounted` which would be seen as a pointer for the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a type already registered with the Godot binding API you can use `godot::Array` or `godot::TypedArray<T>` (which enforces the type of any added item). For that matter `godot::Array` already uses a `godot::Vector<Variant>` under the hood.

You could implement a custom array container as a `godot::RefCounted` but that likely wouldn't act as you would expect, and Godot's own types should be powerful enough for most use cases.

Comment: With `godot::TypedArray<T>` I see that accessing an item on the array returns `godot::Variant`, how can I cast that into my `MyStruct`?

Comment: I believe `godot::Object::cast_to<T>(godot::Object *)` should give you a valid pointer if needed as `godot::Variant` can be a pointer.

Comment: but I'm inheriting from `godot::RefCounted` tho

Comment: `godot::RefCounted` inherits from `godot::Object` so it's valid to cast an object pointer to RefCounted as long as the underlying type inherits from RefCounted. In the case of a RefConted type you can also directly assign the result to a `godot::Ref<T>` as Ref overrides the `=operator` to create a Ref from the pointer. If you want to make sure that it's safe to cast a `godot::Variant` to `godot::Object *` you can check the return of `godot::Variant::get_type()`.

Comment: well, I used `godot::RefCounted::cast_to` and it works fine

Comment: That should be the same method as `RefCounted` inherits it from `Object`.

Comment: Concerning godot::Ref<T> and pointers, there are some good examples in example.cpp in the godot-cpp repo. Concerning the use of Vector<T> i personally had some trouble with this as well, using my own RefCounted subclasses. Works fine with structs though, as long as you keep it in cpp. 
Concerning exposing TypedArray<T> to gdscript, check the link in my answer below. It has a lot of additional context I've discovered since I first posted the answer. Still not entirely resolved though.

Comment: Also, the Vector<T> implementation in gdextension differs slightly from the one in godot engine. Something to be aware of. For example the sort_custom implementation is a little less useful in gdextension

Answer (score -1):

Additional question.

I noticed godot defines a `MAKE_TYPED_ARRAY` macro, which it uses to create the TypedArrray implementations for it's Variants.

Is it necessary or beneficial to use this for our own types? For example:
`MAKE_TYPED_ARRAY(MyClass, Variant::OBJECT)`

EDIT: moved to [How do I properly configure TypedArrays in gdextension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651562/how-do-i-properly-configure-typedarrays-in-gdextension)

Comment: that deserves its question, I think

Comment: Good call. I added a link above.